# How to nest NPM projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to nest a second NPM repository inside the current repository.
Is it possible to create another repo inside an existing repo without inheriting dependencies?

I'm asking this so that I can separate my API and static files

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to have a seperate project for your API. Having it in the same project as your frontend might cause your some trouble when trying to deploy it to a server, or to multiple server for that mather. In term of NPM, as long as you don't import package from the parent, they should be completly independant. Make sure it is in a subfolder though.